# installing Windows from ISO-image

Tags: windows

If I record ISO-image of Windows XP on disc(not files IN image), and after I'll try to install windows on my computer, will my computer be able to read all files from image or not?

Answer (score 6):

No, you won't be able. Most computers do not understand ISO files "natively" (ie. there's no support in BIOS/EFI for mounting ISO files), so the machine will not be able to boot.

You can mount an ISO file as a volume to a VPC, so you can use it to install Windows on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

If your suggesting burning the ISO as a file on a disc and NOT the contents of that ISO my answer would be no.

Answer (score 0):

If you burn the ISO FILE to a CD, no.

If you use a program to burn the ISO CONTENTS to a CD, yes.

ImgBurn is free and can burn ISO's, if that is something you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are many shareware programs that can open and browse ISO image file as file system. I use Total Commander which does it with free extension plugin ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this as you state but you could use WinPE, BartPE or some other PE environment to do this. Load up the PE environment and if it includes a way to mount the ISO you can then start then installer from there but it is more work than it is worth unless you already have a cd that supports this.